OpenApi with generic Pagination Model
I have implemented a pagination in Spring boot and i want to document it. I have created a generic pojo with this structure:
@Getter
@Setter
@Builder
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@JsonPropertyOrder({"content", "number", "size", "totalElements", "totalPages","first", "last"})
@Schema(description = "DTO for paginated response")
public class PageDTO<U> {

  @JsonProperty("content")
  @Schema(description = "Content of a page", example = "generic")
  private List<U> content;

  @JsonProperty("number")
  @Schema(description = "Current page", example = "0")
  private int number;

  @JsonProperty("size")
  @Schema(description = "Size of a page", example = "2")
  private int size;

  @JsonProperty("totalElements")
  @Schema(description = "Total number of element", example = "239")
  private long totalElements;

  @JsonProperty("totalPages")
  @Schema(description = "Total number of pages", example = "120")
  private int totalPages;

  @JsonProperty("first")
  @Schema(description = "First page of the pagination", example = "true")
  private boolean first;

  @JsonProperty("last")
  @Schema(description = "Last page of the pagination", example = "false")
  private boolean last;

}

I have a base class BaseCountryMenuItemProjection . The different implementation will populate the field content of the PageDTO:
@JsonPropertyOrder({"countryName"})
@Schema(description = "Basic information of a country menu item")
public interface BaseCountryMenuItemProjection {

   @JsonProperty("countryName")
   @Schema(description = "Name of the country", example = "India")
   String getCountryName();

}

Example of one implementation CountryMenuItemDetailsProjection :
@JsonPropertyOrder({"area", "countryCode2"})
@Schema(description = "Detailed information of a country menu item")
public interface CountryMenuItemDetailsProjection extends BaseCountryMenuItemProjection {

  @JsonProperty("area")
  @Schema(description = "Area of the country", example = "12345.67")
  BigDecimal getArea();

  @JsonProperty("countryCode2")
  @Schema(description = "2-letter country code", example = "GR")
  String getCountryCode2();

}

In the controller i achieve to populate the List and display to the swagger, base on the path parameter info that i revive from the request.
 @Operation(
        summary = "Get a list of countries with menu items",
        description = "Retrieves a list of countries with their corresponding menu items based on the provided info parameter. The response includes different details based on the type of menu item requested.",
        responses = {
                @ApiResponse(
                        responseCode = "200",
                        description = "Successfully retrieved list of countries",
                        content = @Content(
                                array = @ArraySchema(
                                        schema = @Schema(implementation = CountryMenuItemDetailsProjection.class))
                        )
                ),
        }
)
@GetMapping(path = "/countries/{info}", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public ResponseEntity<PageDTO<BaseCountryMenuItemProjection>> getMenuCountries(
        @PathVariable String info,
        @RequestParam(name = "page", defaultValue = "0", required = false) int page,
        @RequestParam(name = "size", defaultValue = "2", required = false) int size,
        @RequestParam(name = "sortList", defaultValue = "countryName") List<String> sortList,
        @RequestParam(name = "sortOrder", defaultValue = "ASC") Sort.Direction sortOrder
) {
    var pageable = PageRequest.of(page, size, Sort.by(createSortOrder(sortList, sortOrder)));

    var response = countryMenuItemServicesFactory
            .getMenuService(CountryMenuItemType.valueOf(info.toUpperCase()))
            .getMenuItem(pageable);

    return ResponseEntity
            .ok()
            .body(response);
}

How to populate the doc for PageDTO in my controller for the different type of implementation of PageDTO  ?
